# Improper Resource Shutdown or Release

Tags: java, xml, security

Description:
In the code below What am i doing wrong in the code below, in my code audit i got improper resource shutdown or release.
I tried taking out the close and flush from the code below

```
    File someFile = new File(fileName);

                   fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
                   fos.write(data);
                   fos.flush();
                   fos.close();
```

Main code:

```
    FileOutputStream fos=null;
    try {
       Hashtable hash = responseBlob.getAllAttachments();
       Enumeration e = hash.elements();

       while (e.hasMoreElements()) {

     SBADataAttach tmpAttach = (SBADataAttach) e.nextElement();

     String tag = tmpAttach.getTag();
          byte[] data = tmpAttach.getData();
          // encode compressed file
          if (hasTag(tag))
             mimeResponse.addPart(tag, Base64.encodeBytes(data)
                   .getBytes());
          else
             mimeResponse.addPart(tag, data);
          try {

             if (this.configData.getBlobPath() != null) 
    {
                // save compressed file
                String fileName = File.separatorChar + "tmp"
                      + File.separatorChar + tag;
                Log.theLogger.debug("XisServlet.process() ... "
                      + "Save compressed file = " + fileName);


                   File someFile = new File(fileName);
                   fos = new FileOutputStream(
                         someFile);
                   fos.write(data);
                   fos.flush();
                   fos.close();

             }

                   } catch (Exception zipe) {
             Log.theLogger.error(zipe.getMessage(), zipe);
          }
       }
    } catch (SBADataException sde) {
       // cannot detach files from blob
       Log.theLogger.error(sde.getMessage(), sde);
    } 
    finally {
       try {
               if( fos!=null ) {
                  fos.close();
               }
           } catch(IOException e) {
              Log.theLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
           }
          }
```

I don't get any error. But in the Appsec finding i getImproper Resource Shutdown or Release

Comment: Your code might not close `fos` if some code in between `new FileOutputStream(someFile);` and `fos.close()` throws an Exception.

Comment: Do i really need fos.close(); as i am doing fos.close in Finally also finally {
       try {
               if( fos!=null ) {
                  fos.close();
               }
           } catch(IOException e) {
              Log.theLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
           }
          }

Comment: Use a try-with-resource statement.

Comment: I have the changed the code to try{
        //open resources
        File someFile = new File(fileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(data);
       }
       catch(Exception e1){
        //handle exception
       }finally{
        //close resources
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
       }


      }

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
                                //open resources
                                File someFile = new File(fileName);
                                fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
                                fos.write(data);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e1){
                                //handle exception
                            }finally{
                                //close resources
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();
                            }


                        }
```